# Inconsistent result set

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am trying to query in Elasticsearch, but time and again I am getting a different result set from elasticsearch for same query. My cluster is having 3 shards and 2 replicas. My first guess was this might be happening because of shards in action there fore I tried querying with dfs_query_then_fetch but still I am having the same issue, after a lot a searching through I found out that the shard to which it is searching on is changing so I used preference to query. Still I observe the same issue. I am out of options now unable to figure out what is the issue.
Pasting my query here

```
POST _search?search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch&preference=metiswayfinder
{  
   "query":{  
      "multi_match":{  
         "query":"this is a test",
         "fields":[  
            "subject^3",
            "message"
         ]
      }
   },
   "sort":[  
      {  
         "_score":{  
            "order":"desc"
         }
      },
      {  
         "incidentcount":{  
            "order":"desc"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Relevance score is vital for me, also I observe that the score keeps on changing everytime I do a search. Elasticsearch is giving inconsistent result set and inconsistent score. Any way by which I can neutralize these two scenarios without much change.
Adding the segment query result

[image]

Thanks 
Ashit

Comment: How many document do you have in this index?

Comment: I have around 1 million content distributed across 3 shards

Comment: And your tests and results are on this 3 shards index with 1 million documents?

Comment: @AndreiStefan yes

Comment: Do you use custom routing? Can you provide the result of `GET /_cat/segments?v&index=YOUR_INDEX_NAME`

Comment: @AndreiStefan no we are not using custom routing, have added the query result as image in the question. As it was very big so added a part of it please have a look.

Comment: This doesn't help. Can you provide the result of `GET _cat/indices?v&index=YOUR_INDEX_NAME`?

Comment: Here you go health status index pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size green open my_index 3 2 1068358 395023 61.9gb 21.5gb

Comment: You have a bit of deleted documents in there... Any chance you could try your queries on an index where the data has just been indexed into? The idea is that deleted documents do affect the result of the scoring and my assumption is that the different number of deleted documents in each shard is what is giving you different results.

Comment: If you send the same query to a specific shard, like what you did with the preference, my guess is that you would get three different scoring depending on which copy of that shard is being hit. For example: `?preference=_shards:0;_primary`. Do you get the same result every time when you run with this preference?

Comment: I tried running the query as suggested by you but still getting different result but the frequency of change of result set has reduced. but still I am getting different result.

Comment: @AndreiStefan how can I purge the deleted documents, because creating a new index is a time taking task now.. Is there any query available.

Comment: You can use a force_merge call with max_num_segments=1. BUT this will be resource intensive and if your index is still being updated (documents updated, documents deleted) it might be worse on the performance. How frequent does the score change when you run with those preferences that I mentioned?

Comment: @AndreiStefan though the score change is kind of after 5-6 search. But the real issue is I am getting less no of result because the result is concentrated to one shard. So if I don't give a any particular shard I get around 10,000 docs but with when result is concentrated to shard 0, I am getting only 3500 docs. I can't afford that.

Comment: I see. It would be great if you could re-index the data either in a separate index in the same cluster or in a separate/test cluster to check the scoring there. Just to confirm the deleted documents are to blame.

Comment: @AndreiStefan confirmed now its all because of deleted documents, tried testing on another index which was freshly created the score and result set remained same. Also ran purge query on one of the index and tried testing the same query the result set remained same even in multiple query. Now when we know that its because of deleted documents now the question is how to resolve this ???

Comment: How different are the scores? The idea is that with an increasing number of docs the scores should pretty much be almost the same. Thus my question about how many docs there are.

Comment: @AndreiStefan its differing in 100th place of decimal. Trying ways to live with this for time being . Yeah you are right with growing contents the difference should reduce.I am trying to put more contents to see whats the effect.

Comment: Yeah, the idea is that the more documents there are in each shard, the scoring per shard should start to level because all the stats about terms, size of documents etc. tend to become very similar. The more docs there are the more level things should become.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/consistent-scoring.html

According to the comments in your post, it looks like you already identified that deleting documents with replication can cause this issue - though this post helps explain why. In terms of what to do next, the article suggests the following:

> The recommended way to work around this issue is to use a string that identifies the user that is logged is (a user id or session id for instance) as a [preference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-request-preference.html). This ensures that all queries of a given user are always going to hit the same shards, so scores remain more consistent across queries.

I hope that helps!